# Excel Application Formula en Celda

Tags: excel

con visual foxpro hago un excel y en dos de las celdas aplico dos formulas.
La primera sale OK, pero la segunda me aparece en el Excel con #¿Nombre?

1 formula: oSheet.Cells(nFila,nCol).Formula="=H"+as(nFila)+"*C"+as(nFila)
- multiplica dos celdas.. OK

2 formula: oSheet.Cells(nFila,nCol).Formula = "=SUMA("J7:J"+as(nFila-1))"
 - lo que veis de as(... as es una funcion mia para hacer allt(str(...
 - aqui en el excel me aparece como #¿Nombre?.
 - si voy a la formula y le doy al botón de validar, se refresca bien.

que es lo que está mal?
sabeis porque ocurre eso?

Gracias

Comment: Una curiosidad: si en vez de `SUMA` usas `SUM`, que ocurre?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

la propiedad `.Formula` solamente admite fórmulas en inglés. En tu caso, tendrías que poner `"=SUM("J7:J"+as(nFila-1))"`

Pero hay otra propiedad que permite poner las fórmulas según el idioma que uses, se llama **[Range.FormulaLocal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-formulalocal-property-excel)**

Prueba a usar `oSheet.Cells(nFila,nCol).FormulaLocal = "=SUMA("J7:J"+as(nFila-1))"` a ver si te lo coge.

Comment: Gracias Elier... ya podía estar yo dandole vueltas.